# trigger.io recipe shopping list not displaying on web page

Tags: trigger.io

If I run the recipe shopping list in an emulator (IOS/android), everything behaves fine (except the thumbnails which are broken links.

But when I run it as a web page, I get a blank page. I checked and the source code is OK in the blank page, it's just showing nothing.

Comment: What app in particular are you referring to? Have you checked the JS console for errors, when running the web app?

Comment: I'm referring to the sample app on your site. No, I haven't checked the console. Good advice.